# Interrupt registers and interrupt request line(IRQ)

Tags: assembly, operating-system, interrupt

Correct me if im wrong because I'm really bad at getting the correct answer in google.

So as far as I know ,in order for an interrupt to be executed the interrupt request line (IRQ) has to be activated. The specific interrupt handler that is executed is determined by the interrupt number in a specific register. Also I think there's a Library in some operating systems where the interrupt numbers arent changed after an update and you have to implement them in your code.

My question is: What is the assembly code for activating the IRQ and in which register do I have to put the interrupt number into?

Again please correct me if Im wrong before taking down this question. Also keep in mind that im working on windows.

Comment: You might be confusing IRQ, software interrupts and system calls. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: Hardware interrupt mechanism is activated when a device sends the signal IRQ  to processor, this cannot be done by any machine instruction directly. In real Intel CPU mode far pointers to each of 256 possible interrupt handlers are stored at linear addresses 0, 4, 8,12,,,1020.

Comment: @vitsoft, hardware interrupts can be initiated by software by writing to the ICR register in the local APIC.